# How to Reference Connection String in web form that is in web.config file using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ssms

I am starting a new system and i have already stored the connection string in my web.config file. I now want to use that connection string in my web forms. How do i reference it.

This is what I have in my web.config file

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="XX" connectionString="server=XX;UID=XX;PWD=XX;Database=XX" />
    <add name="XXX" connectionString="server=XX;UID=XX;PWD=XX;Database=XX" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

This a web form that i wish to use the connection string maybe in a using statement or something, without having to open and close the connection each time in each form.

```
Protected Sub btnSearchEmployee_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchEmployee.Click

        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("server=XX; Database= XX; Integrated Security = XX")
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM EmployeeCodes WHERE (FirstName LIKE '%' + @firstname + '%') OR (Code = @code) ", conn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSearchEmployee.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtSearchEmployee.Text

        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim tbl As New DataTable()

        adapter.Fill(tbl)

        txtName.Text = ""
        txtSurname.Text = ""
        txtIDNo.Text = ""
        txtCostCentre.Text = ""
        txtDepartment.Text = ""
        txtClockNo.Text = ""



        If tbl.Rows.Count() > 0 Then

            txtName.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(5).ToString()
            txtSurname.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(6).ToString()
            txtIDNo.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(8).ToString()
            txtCostCentre.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(8).ToString()
            txtDepartment.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(8).ToString()
            txtClockNo.Text = tbl.Rows(0)(1).ToString()

            lblSearchEmployee.Visible = False


        Else

            lblSearchEmployee.Visible = True

        End If



    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("XX").ToString())
```

Please check syntax with VB.net if I miss something.

You can use any of the connection string by passing name of that which you have set in web.config file

Comment: Thanks so much @Kevin Shah it worked. So i do not need to use conn.open() and conn.close() in my code as this line already caters for that ?

Comment: no you need to call open() and close() as this just set the connection string. To let SqlConnection know which database it has to connect

Comment: For that you can create a class library to handle conenction through out the application instead of initializing it every where in page.